# Running hubCheck utility from inside K8s's Pod

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I'm trying to run [hubCheck utility](https://genome-blog.soe.ucsc.edu/blog/2017/03/17/how-portable-is-your-track-hub-use-hubcheck-to-find-out/) from inside Kubernetes Pod but for some reason I get this Network error:

```
# I ran hubCheck hubCheck from inside the pod
$ ./hubCheck -noTracks -verbose=2 ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/hub.txt
### kent source version 431 ###
Found 2 problems:
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/hub.txt
TCP non-blocking connect() to ftp.ebi.ac.uk IP 193.62.193.138 timed-out in select() after 10000 milliseconds - Cancelling!
```

However, when I run `hubCheck` locally it works fine.

```
$ ./hubCheck -noTracks -verbose=2 ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/hub.txt
### kent source version 430 ###
1 tracks in sacCer3
1 tracks in mm10
1 tracks in ce10
1 tracks in galGal4
1 tracks in ci2
1 tracks in danRer7
1 tracks in dm6
1 tracks in hg38
```

The first thing I checked is if the pod has access to the internet, which was the case as you can see below, I can use curl to download `hubCheck`:

```
# curl -o tools/hubCheck http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/admin/exe/linux.x86_64/hubCheck
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 33.2M  100 33.2M    0     0  10.0M      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 10.0M
```

I thought this may be caused by a firewall limiting the access to external URL, but I don't think it's the case because other URLs like the one below is working fine both outside and inside K8s:

```
$ ./hubCheck -noTracks -verbose=2 http://younglab.wi.mit.edu/mESC_ChIAPET_hub/hub.txt
### kent source version 431 ###
4 tracks in mm9
```

**Edit 1:**

Experiminting with replacing `ftp` with `http` gave as @larsks suggested:

```
$ ./hubCheck -noTracks -verbose=2 http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/hub.txt
### kent source version 431 ###
0 tracks in hg38
0 tracks in mm10
0 tracks in ce10
0 tracks in galGal4
0 tracks in ci2
0 tracks in danRer7
0 tracks in dm6
0 tracks in sacCer3
Found 10 problems:
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/C_elegans/trackDb.txt
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/C_intestinalis/trackDb.txt
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/D_melanogaster/trackDb.txt
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/D_rerio/trackDb.txt
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/G_gallus/trackDb.txt
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/H_sapiens_hg38/trackDb.txt
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/M_musculus_mm10/trackDb.txt
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/S_cerevisiae/trackDb.txt
TCP non-blocking connect() to ftp.ebi.ac.uk IP 193.62.193.138 timed-out in select() after 10000 milliseconds - Cancelling!
warning: ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/hub_description.html descriptionUrl setting does not exist
```

~I'm not sure if it is related to the transfer protocol.~

**Edit 2:**

After some digging, I realized that indeed, it definitely has something to do with FTP

From inside the pod using FTP

```
$ ./hubCheck -noTracks -verbose=2 ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/misc_data/Track_Hubs/SRP039045/hub.txt
### kent source version 432 ###
Found 2 problems:
Couldn't open ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/misc_data/Track_Hubs/SRP039045/hub.txt
TCP non-blocking connect() to ftp.ensemblgenomes.org IP 193.62.193.141 timed-out in select() after 10000 milliseconds - Cancelling!
```

From inside the pod using HTTP (Working fine)

```
$ ./hubCheck -noTracks -verbose=2 http://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/misc_data/Track_Hubs/SRP039045/hub.txt
### kent source version 432 ###
1 tracks in IRGSP-1.0
Found 8 problems:
warning: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/fg/rnaseq/api/json/70/getRunsByStudy/SRP039045 descriptionUrl setting does not exist
warning: missing description page for track: 'SAMN02649582'
warning: missing description page for track: 'SAMN02649583'
warning: missing description page for track: 'SAMN02649584'
warning: missing description page for track: 'SRP039045_composite'
warning: missing description page for track: 'SRR1178905'
warning: missing description page for track: 'SRR1178906'
warning: missing description page for track: 'SRR1179192'
```

Now I know what the problem is but I have no idea how to fix it.

When I check the Nginx ingress services available on the cluster I found HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) available but nothing about FTP.

Will creating an FTP ingress controller solve the issue? are there any security concerns?

Comment: It looks like those sames files are available using `http://` instead of `ftp://`. Assuming that the `hubCheck` command supports `http`, what happens if you try `./hubCheck -noTracks -verbose=2 http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/Rfam/12.0/genome_browser_hub/hub.txt`?

Comment: @larsks, thanks for taking the time, I updated my question including your suggestion

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping it just an ftp related problem :).

Comment: I wish it was, based on the previous discussions I found online [[1](https://groups.google.com/a/soe.ucsc.edu/g/genome/c/4q_Hzan0cg8), [2](https://groups.google.com/a/soe.ucsc.edu/g/genome/c/tj3CxdXFD7U)] it seems that this mainly happens when track hubs are not in publicly-accessible locations which is not the case here :/

Comment: @larsks, you were indeed right about changing ftp to http
Can you please take a look at the updated post and let me know what you think?

Comment: I think you fix it by using the `http://` url instead of the `ftp://` url. Is that not an option for some reason?

Comment: That would be tricky because each hub.txt file points to many other files which contain FTP URLs that hubCkeck checks against, in this case we will need to ask the submitter to change all those url from `ftp://` to `http://` which may not be faisable